# Replace map character with string number

Tags: string, go, integer

I have string with arabic number. How to replace this character from map numbers?

**String:** `000۲۱۷۹۰۰`

**my code:**

```
var digitconv = map[string]int{"۰":0, "۱":1, "۲":2, "۳":3, "۴":4, "۵":5, "۶":6, "۷":7, "۸":8, "۹":9}

func main() {
    num := "000۲۱۷۹۰۰"
    chk, _ := regexp.Match("", num)
    fmt.Println(chk)
}
```

Comment: Don't use a regex. Regex is almost always the wrong tool. Just use `strings.ReplaceAll` in a for loop, or `strings.Map` or a `strings.Replacer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [`strings.Map()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Map):

```
var digitconv = map[rune]rune{
    '۰': '0', '۱': '1', '۲': '2', '۳': '3', '۴': '4',
    '۵': '5', '۶': '6', '۷': '7', '۸': '8', '۹': '9',
}
num := "000۲۱۷۹۰۰"
fmt.Println(num)

s := strings.Map(func(r rune) rune {
    if r2, ok := digitconv[r]; ok {
        return r2
    }
    return r
}, num)

fmt.Println(s)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/AMroUEWZypY)):

```
000۲۱۷۹۰۰
000217900
```